# How to create this Mathematica animation in beamer

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

I apologize in advance if my question seems confusing or trivial.

How to successfully create an animated PDF Beamer for this *Animation Mathematica* file, available on the following link
[European Option Prices and Greeks in 3D](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EuropeanOptionPricesAndGreeksIn3D/).

It seems it's impossible as we can't use the **Mathematica** player in .**cdf** format.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use `media9` package. For details, refer to its documentation.

Comment: Hm, it's not Flash, but some proprietary format (.cdf) requiring a player from Wolfram. Thus `media9` doesn't help.

Comment: @Harish Kumar. Thank you for this advice. I'll look more closely.

Comment: @AlexG. Thank's also. But what did you mean by proprietary format(.cdf).

Comment: Wolfram's CDF-Player is required for viewing this kind of files (*.cdf). The CDF file format doesn't seem to be open (with a public language specification).

Comment: @AlexG.I believe it's impossible to successfully create this animation in Beamer since Wolfram's CDF-Player isn't open with a public language specification

Comment: Yeah, this is what I said.

Comment: @AlexG. So I'll change the title of this post as follow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9295/discussion-between-jonas-and-alexg)

Comment: @AlexG Could you make your comments here into an answer?

Answer (score 4):

CDF is a proprietary animation format from Wolfram (owned by Wolfram). Neither the PDF specification nor Adobe specific extensions to it make provision for embedded CDF playback. Thus, there is little chance to find a PDF viewer with an appropriate plugin.